# I downvoted a wrong answer to my question, he deletes it and downvoted my question!

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

What should I do if I downvote the wrong answer and the author of answer comes and deletes his downvoted answer and downvotes my question without any reason!!

Link - [mysql order by IN clause maximum matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522765/mysql-order-by-in-clause-maximum-matches)

Comment: Nothing, though this behavior is toxic.

Comment: @nhahtdh: provided they actually voted. You cannot know if they did or not. And even then they are entitled to vote any way they wish.

Comment: Remember that he doesn't know whether it was you who downvoted the answer, and you don't know for 100% sure whether it was him who downvoted the question. (Edit: ah, Martijn beat me to it)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm talking about the behavior. Whether the person actually does it is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd like to add that as a general rule, IMO it is the polite thing not to downvote answers to your own questions as long as they were given in good faith, and of a minimum of quality - at least not straight away. The community will do that for you. Remember, for many who don't much care about rep the *only* motivation for answering is to help you out.

Comment: There are multiple plausible explanations.  Starting with him concluding that your question was not clear enough, leading him astray and wasting ten minutes of his life.  If you need to post an update to your question to stop SO users from mis-interpreting it then, yeah, that was a problem with your question.  It is rare for SO users to come back and look at the edited version, especially when you poked them with a sharp stick before.

Comment: After looking around, I think the downvote might be justified, and due to the reasons @HansPassant has pointed out. That question of yours is rather unclear.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree with you , I provide two evidence which will make sense . 1 - I updated the answer with details for those who posted wrong answers. 2 - It was almost 3-4 hours of inactivity and suddenly I get negative rep notification and I check one of the authors profile to see last active 1 min ago and at the same time his answer disappears from my question , now atleast I can understand this circumstance

Comment: Its a rather logical sequence of actions. The answer is wrong, thus it is deleted and then comes the thought "well then the question is rather poorly written -> downvote". So what's wrong with the downvote? Perfectly logical.

Comment: @Gimby Downvoting my answer is not a problem for me, user is entitled to downvote for correct reason not for revernge. If he found the question poorly written then he would have downvoted earlier, not when I downvoted his untested, unresearched, false answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Nothing.** *Move along*.

He's entitled to delete his answer.
He's also entitled to use his votes how he pleases. You also have no evidence that *it was actually him* who downvoted your question.

**If** he gets rude or abusive however, that *is* a problem; in that case, flag the offending comments/ posts, and a moderator will take care of it.